# Can you explain why my answer got deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [TypeError when trying to explain weights of XGBoost Classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341027/typeerror-when-trying-to-explain-weights-of-xgboost-classifier/68323991#68323991)

This was my deleted answer:

> I get the same error when using Eli5 with Xgboost 1.4.0. However, with Xgboost 1.3.0 and earlier versions the error goes away.

My answer showed that the error did go away with an earlier version of the package. Why was this deleted? It is obviously useful. This is my first contribution to Stack Overflow. It was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Probably the moderator only read the first sentence, and thought it was a "me too" post, not an answer.

Comment: I've edited that answer once more and raised a custom mod flag to have it undeleted. And I had smokey make some coffee for the mod involved: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52601701#52601701

Comment: I can't actually answer for the moderator who deleted the answer as to why. However, the most likely thing to have happened is what's described by user000001. I've undeleted your answer.

Comment: Reads more like a workaround than an actual answer, but a workaround is still a whole lot better than nothing. In the future I would be a little careful with answers such as these though, if it is that short and only a workaround that can attract downvotes. If "downgrade" is the answer, then usually you should be able to point to some kind of bugreport in the newer version that details the regression. That kind of information helps to solidify the usefulness of your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When posting an answer it helps to make it as clear as possible what the actual solution is. This answer looks like it is providing a solution, but it's very easy to miss what that solution actually is. Rene has provided a really good edit. Take note of what Rene did to make the solution stand out.

The reason why it was deleted is, the mod probably saw the first part of the text and thought that you are only complaining about the same problem, not explaining how to fix the issue. I didn't flag it, but as you can see, I also tried to edit the unnecessary fluff. Adding things like "hope it helps" is only noise and wastes readers time. It certainly does not make it easier to see the solution.